# How not to lose the connection BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to make a BLE communication between TI device and my app. At this moment, not enabling the pairing, everything works well, as soon as the pairing is enabled I have problems.

1) My app asks me for the paired.
2) Enter with passkey
3) The APP not works
4) I leave the APP, return and it works
5) I re-exit from the APP, re-entry does not work and requires the paired.

How can I resolve these errors?

I use this in MainActivity:

```
private void getpaireddevices(){
    Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices();
    if(devicesArray.size() > 0) {
        for(BluetoothDevice device : devicesArray) {
            device.getName();
            device.getAddress();
        }
    }
}
```

And this in SelectedDevice:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver4 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, -1);
        int prevstate = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, -1);

        String msg = "Bond state change: state" + pairstate(state) + "previous state" + pairstate(prevstate);
        Log.w("Bond state receiver", msg);
    }

    private String pairstate(int state) {

        switch (state) {
            case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING:
                Log.i("Bondind status:", "Bonding..");
                break;
            case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED:
                Log.i("Bondind status:", "Bonded");
                break;
            case BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE:
                Log.i("Bondind status:", "Fail");
            default:
                return String.valueOf(state);

        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

In the main activity when I scan devices, I call the `createBond ()` and in SelectedDevice I call the register of `mBroadcastReceiver4`.

Answer (score 0):

The first step in interacting with a BLE device is connecting to it— more specifically, connecting to the GATT server on the device.

```
bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback);


private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback =
            new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
                int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                connectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        bluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                connectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange() status = " + status + " newState = " + newState);
            }
        }

    @Override
    // New services discovered
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    // Result of a characteristic read operation
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
            int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    }
}
```

What log do you see in onConnectionStateChange() when you try to connect to your device ?

Do you discover any service on your device ?

For more infos on connecting to a BLE device:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: Yes, I have this in my MainActivity code. But not change nothing, I have the same problem. When I exit When I exit my app and click "connect", I don't read "STATE CONNECTED" in the logs

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint at the beginning of onConnectionStateChange() and see if you can read a GATT_CONN_TERMINATE_LOCAL_HOST status or STATE_DISCONNECTED newSate ?

Comment: Do you break into onConnectionStateChange() ? If not it means you're not even connecting to the device

Comment: yes, i enter onconectionstatechange, but i not communicate with her

Comment: What are the status and newState values ?